# Grouping per column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this data below

```
item    category    accounts
ITEM1   CATEGORY1   ACCOUNT1
ITEM2   CATEGORY1   ACCOUNT1
ITEM3   CATEGORY2   ACCOUNT2
ITEM4   CATEGORY2   ACCOUNT2
ITEM5   CATEGORY3   ACCOUNT3
ITEM6   CATEGORY3   ACCOUNT3
```

And was wondering what's the better way so I can get it to output like

```
item    category    accounts
ITEM1   CATEGORY1   ACCOUNT1
ITEM2   CATEGORY1   
ITEM3   CATEGORY2   ACCOUNT2
ITEM4   CATEGORY2   
ITEM5   CATEGORY3   ACCOUNT3
ITEM6   CATEGORY3
```

I have tried using UNION:

```
SELECT 
item,
category,
account

FROM t1

UNION

SELECT NULL,NULL,account from t1
```

But the result I got was

```
item    category    accounts
ITEM1   CATEGORY1   ACCOUNT1
ITEM2   CATEGORY1   ACCOUNT1
ITEM3   CATEGORY2   ACCOUNT2
ITEM4   CATEGORY2   ACCOUNT2
ITEM5   CATEGORY3   ACCOUNT3
ITEM6   CATEGORY3   ACCOUNT3
NULL    NULL        ACCOUNT1
NULL    NULL        ACCOUNT2
NULL    NULL        ACCOUNT3
```

Any suggestion on how I can make it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT @acct := null;
SELECT item, category, (if(@acct = account, '', @acct := account)) account FROM items;
```

But I wouldn't really recommend doing that except as a way to more conveniently view the result from the mysql cli tool. (You'll probably also want to adjust the select query and specify an appropriate ORDER BY.)